# D3 line graph and React

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to draw a simple line graph using d3 but I can draw just the axes.
I mean: I got the area defined, the graph title, the axes but no line. The problem seems to be in the last "svg..." cal. I checked other examples but I was not able to find my error.

I guess it is a trivial error but ...I am stuck :(

Could you help me?

here is the code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import rawdata from './lineData';
import * as d3 from "d3";

export default function LineGraph(props){
    const margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30 }
    const width = props.width - margin.left - margin.right
    const height = props.width - margin.top - margin.bottom

    let data=rawdata;

    const d3svg = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data && d3svg.current) {
            let svg = d3.select(d3svg.current);

            const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain(d3.extent(data.map(d => d.temperature)))
                .range([height, 0])
                .nice();
            const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([data[0].date, data[data.length -1].date])
                .range([0, width])
                .nice();

            svg = svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)

            // draw header
            svg
                .append('g')
                .attr('class', 'bar-header')
                .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${-margin.top / 2})`)
                .append('text')
                .append('tspan')
                .text('Line chart')

            // draw axes
            const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
            svg
                .append('g')
                .attr('class', 'x axis')
                .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height})`)
                .call(xAxis)
            const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickSize(0)
            svg
                .append('g')
                .attr('class', 'y axis')
                .call(yAxis)

            svg.selectAll("line")
                .data(data)
                .append("path")
                .enter()
                .attr('class', 'line')
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("stroke", 'blue')
                .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", d3.line()
                  .x(d => xScale(d.date))
                  .y(d => yScale(d.value))
                );  
        }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [data])

  if (data === null) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
  } else
  return (
    <div className='graphContainer'>
        <svg
        className="line-chart-container"
        width={width + margin.left + margin.right}
        height={height + margin.top + margin.bottom}
        role="img"
        ref={d3svg}
        ></svg>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: try `svg.selectAll(".line").data(data).enter().append("path").attr("class", "line")` ? you have appended line before `enter()`

Comment: I tried but nothing changed

Comment: I noticed an error (I did so many tests that instead of solve my problem I added more mistakes :( ). The error is on the last line of the suspected code: ".y(d => yScale(d.value))"  has to be corrected in ".y(d => yScale(d.temperature))". Anyway the problem is still here

Comment: if it's single linechart, try use `datum()` instead of `data()` since the all the data should be bind by one path? or provide a runnable code example so that we can be more clearer

Comment: ...nothing changed. The code is runnable, you have just to add "                <LineGraph
                    width={300}
                    height={300}
                />"  to your App.js file

Comment: I guess that this issue could be reproduced in a code snippet on this page (possibly just the d3 code, without the React part). If so, that'd increase the chance that someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. As it happens often, the solution is an easy one.
Here is the piece of code:

> ```
>         svg.append("path")
>             .datum(data)
>             .attr("fill", "none")
>             .attr("stroke", "blue")
>             .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
>             .attr("d", d3.line()
>                 .x(d => xScale(d.date))
>                 .y(d => yScale(d.temperature)));
> ```